# android thread issue

Tags: android

i have an android application to display the images downloaded from the server. downloading of the image is one thread and displaying that image in main class. on compiling the emulator shows an error alert that application is stopped unexcpectedly. Is the main application(class that extends Activity) a Thread?? Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [adb logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) to get more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Every Android app is by default uni-threaded and this means all the activities (in fact, all the components) run in a single thread. So, the main application is a thread.

Regarding your exception, can you provide more details? Or you try debugging the app right from eclipse. You will get better idea that way.

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       data = GprsConnection.getGprsConnData("url");
      }
    }).start();

Comment: In main class I wrote the code that shown below.this method is to get the gprs connection and read the byte array from the server.When i debug the application iam getting an alert that "Waiting for the debugger to connect". After some seconds i can debug the application. But when I Run the application am getting an alert that"Error: The Application has stopped unexpectedly  Force close".           new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       data = GprsConnection.getGprsConnData("url");
      }                                                                   
    }).start();

Comment: Your code seems to be pretty clean.

Can you go to DDMS perspective and check the logcat tool for the exact error messages?

Comment: are you accessing data just after starting the thread? how are you initializing the data?